# Al ejecutar mi función javascript, manda el código pero se borra de inmediato

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tengo esta función en mi .js:

```
function mandarTeatro(){
    document.getElementById("mainPage").innerHTML = "<p>Esta es la sección teatral</p>";
}
```

Y la cuestión es que, cuando la mando llamar mediante un "onclick", escribe eso en una  de mi html principal, peor el punto es que, inmediatamente que lo escribe, me regresa a como estaba inicialmente, ¿por qué está pasando eso?

Aquí el html, si lo posteaba aquí no me iba a dejar:
https://pastebin.com/JPHbmDw7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` es una propiedad de los elementos `HTML` en este caso se refiere a cualquier texto enriquecido que se encuentre **dentro** de ese elemento, ademas de `HTML` interpretable o procesable.

por ejemplo:

```
<div>
   <nav>Menu</nav>    <!-- Este seria el texto enriquecido --->
</div>
```

Por naturaleza aunque un elemento contenga en si definido otras etiquetas `HTML` junto con texto su propiedad `innerHTML` siempre se encontrara vacia, a no ser de que nosotros la modifiquemos.

Ahora bien, si tu modificas el `innerHTML` de un elemento lo que estas haciendo es sobreescribir el cuerpo de ese elemento con lo que tu le pusiste al `innerHTML`, por lo tanto, es como **reemplazar todo aquello que se encuentre dentro de esa etiqueta por lo que tu le indiques**:

```js
const miContenedor = document.getElementById("miContenedor");
miContenedor.innerHTML = "";
```

```html
<div id = "miContenedor">
  <p>Hola mundo!</p>
</div>
```

Como vemos al asignarle algo a la propiedad `innerHTML` de nuestro div el cuerpo desaparece, debido a lo que hemos explicado antes.

**Pero entonces como hacemos que se conserve el cuerpo para anadir lo que necesitemos?**

Muy facil simplemente en vez de utilizar una asignacion: `=`.

Deberas usar una concatenacion: `+=`

De esta manera se conserva lo que ya contenia de por si la etiqueta en su cuerpo y se le añade al final lo que tu definiste, veamos un ejemplo:

```js
const miContenedor = document.getElementById("miContenedor");
miContenedor.innerHTML += "<h1>Esta etiqueta fue anadida por medio de innerHTML!</h1>";
```

```html
<div id = "miContenedor">
  <p>Hola mundo!</p>
</div>
```

Como vemos el cuerpo se conserva y se añade el elemento o elementos indicados a manera de **HTML** que es el efecto deseado.

Recordemos que **concatenacion** significa anadirle a algo que ya existe un elemento o varios, por ejemplo a un `string` le podemos concatenar otro `string` fusionando ambos en uno solo sin que se pierda la informacion de uno u otro.

Basicamente la asignacion estaba borrando el contenido del elemento, pero con una concatenacion rescatamos ese contenido y le pegamos el que necesitamos.

Comment: function mandarTeatro(){
    const secccionPrincipal = document.getElementById("mainPage");
    secccionPrincipal.innerHTML += "<p>Esta es la sección teatral</p>";
}
pero me sigue haciendo lo mismo, me manda bien el código html pero me lo reescribe igual, editaré en el post principal el código de la página html, a lo mejor es algo de ahí.

Comment: A que te refieres con "Me lo reescribe igual"?, que deseas hacer realmente?

Comment: Me refiero a que, con el "+=" me hace el mismo efecto que son simplemente el "=", me lo muestra un segundo, luego de inmediato lo borra

Comment: @shiosaku creo que hay algo en el codigo que te borra los elementos, seguramente otro `innerHTML` que tienes por ahi que no estas tomando en cuenta, ya que por defecto esto deberia funcionar, debes mirar bien en el codigo si hay algo mas que interactua con ese elemento.

Comment: pero no tengo ningún otro script activo, solo ese, y en realidad solo son esas 3 líneas de código del script

Comment: @shiosaku fijate en ambos snippets, el primero (sin el +=) y el segundo (con el +=), al ejecutarlos hay claramente una diferencia, debe haber algo mas, hay que buscar, hay algo que los borra, o tu envias informacion a otra parte?

Comment: Al final lo logré, el objeto que mandaba a llamar la función tenía la tag <a> con un href en blanco, así que supongo que al darle click estaba intentando llamar a ese hipervinculo en blanco por eso me hacía el refresh.